# Como puedo agregar un CheckBox y un div con un Icono y que sea responsivo?-HTML

Tags: html, css, responsive

Estoy realizando un formulario y en uno de los campos requiere un checkbox el cual dice "Requiere de servicio especializado" me pidieron que se le agregue un icono de una silla de ruedas alado del Checkbox pero al agregarlo se me va para abajo el icono, ya que este formulario será responsivo al momento de reducir la resolución se me pasa para abajo.
Como podría agrupar el CheckBox y el Icono? para que no se me moviera y se vea responsivo? y que el icono sea grande para que ocupe mas lugar dentro del circulo y poder cambiarle el color del icono para que se vea mas presentable?

Esto es lo que tengo actualmente en base al Checkbox y el icono

```css
.dot {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  background-color: #00aae4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label for="vehicle3">Requiere de servicio Especializado</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat"><br>
<div class="dot fas fa-wheelchair ">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si usas bootstrap 5 -y creo que podrías aprovecharlo mas- agrúpalos en un `input-group`.
Para el icono aprovecha la funcionalidad de apilamiento de fontawesome.

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label>Requiere de servicio Especializado</label>
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
  </div>
  <div class=" fa-stack fa-2x">
    <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:#00aae4"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-wheelchair fa-stack-1x" ></i>
  </div>
</div>
```